# How to setup a Netbeans / Git / Cygwin environment to not choke on CR and LF differences - e.g: `\r command not found`?

Tags: git, bash, netbeans, cygwin, newline

I use Netbeans, Git and Cygwin on Windows 7  and am constantly fighting issues around CR and LF differences for line endings.

2 main issues are :

- Git gives a 'modified' status when the only difference is that the repo uses LF and the staged file has a CRLF .  errrrg.
- I get `\r command not found` when trying to run a script within Netbeans, which has been configured to use my cygwin bash. This is because Cygwin doesnt like CRLF.

**What I want:**

- LF line endings in all text files, both in repo and working directory
- Prevent Netbeans from changing line endings to CRLF
- Prevent cygwin from choking on CRLF

**What I've tried:**

- added SHELLOPTS=igncr in my Windows environmental variable. This works to keep Cygwin happy so it digests my bash scripts without choking, but I want a solution that doesn't rely on this workaround. It seems clunky and is really just hiding the issue.
- tried the [GitHub line ending solution](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) including setting autorclf=false, text=auto in my gitattributes file. This works, unless I try to run the bash file using Cygwin after its been edited by Netbeans. Then Netbeans chokes ( unless I use the workaround SHELLOPTS=igncr)

There are similar questions but none that I can find that addresses this specific ( but common ) environment, especially pertaining to the bash script issue.

Comment: From your description, it seems configuring NetBeans to accept LF on that project could solve the problem (it is possible for IDEs like Eclipse, and it should be similar). Git and Cygwin should be happy then too. It is also important to *decide* for either CRLF or LF for your team and you. The repository should be the default for everyone in the team.